# Method for imaging a HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, imaging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Imaging new hard drive in Windows 7 laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/190619/imaging-new-hard-drive-in-windows-7-laptop)

I have to image my 320gb Laptop HDD before I send it in for repairs. The HDD is likely going to get replaced, and I would ideally like to be able to restore everything as I have it now without having to reinstall my OSes, programs and place all my files back again.

I can make space on an external HDD I have, so am just looking for how I should go about this.

Should I just use dd with a linux rescue cd? Or is there perhaps a more suitable program with its own rescue disk?

Comment: @Sathya, @slhck, @bubu This is not an exact duplicate, as the other answers and question are specific to Windows. I have several partitions, of which only one is windows. As such the windows specific solutions in the other question are useless to me. Please reopen. @Sathya, stop closing so many questions prematurely.

Comment: there's this thing where you you should be specific about what OS you're using, what OS are you targetting that should be filled in to the question. We're not mind readers here. My suggestion: Stop clicking on ask a question prematurely before giving all the details.  Also, did you even look at all the answers? these answers: ref [1](http://superuser.com/questions/190619/imaging-new-hard-drive-in-windows-7-laptop/190796#190796), [2](http://superuser.com/questions/190619/imaging-new-hard-drive-in-windows-7-laptop/190625#190625) are not specific to Windows.

Comment: @Sathya, I clearly state in my question that I have multiple OSes on my hdd, and am looking for a way to image the hdd at a low enough level that I could restore them all. Now, should I ask my question again, or can I get this reopened? I really recommend you stop closing questions as dupes as a conditioned response just because you think they *may* be. The only answer in the other question not specific to windows or a single partition is Clonezilla, and now I am unable to see if there may well be better alternatives since you erroneously closed this as a dupe.

Comment: maybe cloning is normally done only on a per partition basis. Perhaps you should ask differently, how do you clone all partitions at once, from one hard drive to another. Not each partition individually.